# Message Status Feature On StackOverflow

Tags: feature-request, notifications

In WhatsApp, they have a 'tick, double-tick, blue-doubletick' feature so that the sender knows the status of his message.

Similarly, for answers and comments, a feature like that, visible to the senders would help them know whether the message/comment has seen by the-user-who-is-ment-to-read-it, rather than waiting for a reply to know whether he read the answer/comment or not.

So should a feature like that be introduced in Stack Exchange? Are there any barriers preventing this from being implemented?

Comment: What difference does it make if a message is read or not in terms of the waiting? If somebody hasn't read a message yet, you'd wait. If they have read the message...you'd still have to wait. Also, ultimately any messages shouldn't be *to a user*. Sure we can @-notify people but comments are public. And answers even more so - an answer is *not* for the sole use of the question asker. The asker is the extreme minority of the audience - everybody who visits the question will be able to see the answer.

Comment: *Or is their any barriers* yes, social distancing. Lets not turn SE into a social network

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show if/when the answer was seen by the author of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169964/show-if-when-the-answer-was-seen-by-the-author-of-the-question) - the reasons explained there apply to any kind of post, may it be a Q/A or a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think this should be implemented. It's nice in instant messaging, because that's a platform for real-time communication. Stack Exchange isn't; we're [working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) [insert topic here]. A *library*, so basically the opposite of real-time; content here is meant for eternity (or until outdated).

If you want any (but hardly reliable) indication whether a user has read your comment or answer, check their profile for when they were last active. This doesn't always work; they might have read their inbox while on another site, or (in my case, for as long as it continues to work) read the push notification in the Stack Exchange mobile app.

Answer (score 4):

> So should a feature like that be introduced in SO? Or is their any barriers protecting this from being implemented?

#### No, that shouldn't be implemented.

Since SE sites aren't meant for personal help, but rather for keeping repositories of questions and answers useful for future research, I don't see how such feature would be an improvement.